# My form is for 2 objects, can I embed 2 objects somehow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

When my form gets posted, it will first create my model object#1, and if it succeeds, then it will create model object#2.

My form field needs to have a mix of both input fields for both model objects.

Can I do this using form helpers or should I just do this manually?

**Update**

Below are my models:

My models:

```
Account
  has_many :users
  has_one  :primary_user, :class_name => 'User'

User
  has_one :account
```

My user table has:

```
account_id
```

My account table:

```
primary_user_id
```

**So during registration/signup for an account, I want to also include the fields from the user object:**

```
user_name
email
password
```

**So when the account is created, the primary_user user account is also created.**

How can I do this?

PSS:  Which side of the associate should be nullable, the account_id on the user table or the primary_user on the account side?  Because currently I have no nulls on both sides and that won't work!

Comment: Are the objects associated? If so Nested Models will take care of that... still some work but the form helpers are still in place for you.

Comment: no its not nested, but it actually should be.

Comment: The relation will be a has_one relation.

Comment: It might be worth checking out the Railscasts on it if you have not already: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1. I am by no means an expert so I apologize if you are beyond this already.

Comment: I updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model code**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_one  :primary_user, :class_name => "User", 
    :conditions => {:is_primary => true}

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :primary_user, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**Controller Code**

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @account = Account.new(:primary_user => User.new)
  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(params[:account])
    if @account.save
      flash[:info] = "Created account"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

**View code**

```
- semantic_form_for @account do |f|
  - f.inputs do
    != f.input :company_name
    != f.input :address
    != f.input :city
    != f.input :state
    - f.semantic_fields_for :primary_user do |puf|
      != f.input :name
      != f.input :login
      != f.input :password
      != f.input :password_confirmation
  - f.buttons  do
    != f.commit_button 'Save'
    ! #{link_to 'Cancel', root_url}
```

Comment: so calling save on account will save user also?

Comment: Yes, nested attributes takes care of storing user object.